# Is there a sql only way to turn a hierarchical table into a set of json strings?

Tags: sql-server, json

I have a hierarchical table a simplified version of which might look like this:

```
id parentid text
-- -------- ----
1  null     A
2  1        Ax
3  1        Ay
4  3        Ay2
5  null     B
6  5        Bx
```

I want to migrate all the data from this table in json form. The result of the table above should end up looking like:

```
{
  "text":"A",
  "children":
  [
    {
      "text":"Ax",
      "children":[]
    },
    {
      "text":"Ay",
      "children":
      [
        {
          "text":"Ay2",
          "children":[]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(next record)

```
{
  "text":"B",
  "children":
  [
    {
      "text":"Bx",
      "children":[]
    }
  ]
}
```

The table has several hundred thousand records and I can't really make an assumption as to how deep it recurses as this might change before I finally run it. I'd looked into using WITH to try to concatenate the child records but I'm really struggling. Can this be done with WITH or is there another way?

Comment: Why does it have to be SQL only? Even using a scripting language this will be much easier.

Comment: This could get you some of the way (if not all I haven't read it!). http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: @OrangeDog - It doesn't "have" to be but I just wanted to be sure before I start using cursors or looking elsewhere for a solution. All my data migration stuff is done in SQL so far which makes for an easy deployment.

Comment: @Martin - interesting, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I went with a recursive sql function with a cursor that concatenates the results of each recursive call. Another sql function escapes the strings that go into the json to make sure there are no nasty characters in there.

This last function based on some of the code in the link @Martin provided in the comments above: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

I normally keep well away from cursors but as this is a data migration script it proved the simplest way forward

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult doing this type of thing in SQL, as it is expecting to return a set of rows (ie: a grid or table). If you are using PL/SQL or another procedural language built into sql you could approximate it, but the best solution would be to call SQL statements from within a script or other code, as you did.

PS: Cursors are very useful, once you get used to them. Think of them as a loop: on each row you can perform some logic.